# Unable to find Max Age of a Player

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am a newbie to SQL. 
I wanna find out what which player is oldest by age.
So here is my table..
[image: SQL table]

Somehow my Query give error.
Can you please tell me where i am doing it wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from players 
where age = (select max(age) as Oldest_Player from players);
limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL has a `SELECT TOP` command, which allows you to retrieve a set number of rows. You can do `SELECT TOP 1 name AS 'Oldest Person' FROM players ORDER BY age DESC`

What this will do is: first retrieve all the players, sort them by age descending (oldest first), then take the first one.

Comment: this is very inefficient because sort is O(n log n) but max is linear, just O(N). not sure if there is a better way in SQL though, not a SQL expert.

Comment: That's true, but I believe MAX is used within the `SELECT` part of the statement, in which you have to first make a pass to determine the `MAX`, store it and then use a `WHERE` to find it. If the OP is interested, this question addresses that method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column albeit being a bit more complicated but faster over larger data sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number as below:

```
Select * from (
   Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over(order by age desc) from Players 
   ) a Where a.RowN = 1
```